# How to create Transparence Thumbnail Gallery?

Tags: android, image, gallery, image-gallery

hy there, i will create Android Gallery on my app, but this not perfect because use old Interface, i hope my Gallery look modern UI, can you help, my Gallery look like this :

[image]

i want my gallery look like this :)

[image]

this is my code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@null"

>

 <Gallery
    android:id="@+id/gallery1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"

  />

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:scaleType="matrix" 
   android:background="@null"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

and my Activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
//---raw---
Integer[] imageID = {
    R.drawable.gbr1,
    R.drawable.gbr2,
    R.drawable.gbr3,
    R.drawable.gbr4
};

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
      {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Foto" + (position + 1) + " dipilih", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //---show click img---
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageID[position]);
      }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int itemBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        context = c;
        //---style---
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 1);
        a.recycle();
    }

    //--- back  mount picture---
    public int getCount() {
        return imageID.length;
    }

    //---back ID item---
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---back ID item---
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---back view ImageView---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageID[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
        return imageView;
    }
}       
}
```

thanks for All before :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use traditional components that are exist in the Github (github.com) for this purpose.
Or design it by yourself (that's more flexible way!)
But it may need to write couple of custom controls to achieve the appearance you want.
Both pictures you attached, almost have the same core (Code Behind) and the main difference between them is their design.